# asp.net mvc не отображаются данные в представлении

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

внутри он есть, но на страницу не выводится 
как выглядит дебаг
[image: рисунок из дебага]

как выглядит в браузере
[image: отображение на форме]
класс для хранения значений

```
public class Calculator
{
    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double res;

    public double A
    {
        get
        {
            return a;
        }

        set
        {
            a = value;
        }
    }

    public double B
    {
        get
        {
            return b;
        }

        set
        {
            b = value;
        }
    }

    public double Res
    {
        get
        {
            return res;
        }

        set
        {
            res = value;
        }
    }
}
```

страница cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@model ASPMVCLesson4.Models.Calculator

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.A);
    @:
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.B);
    @: =
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Res);
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="+" name="action:Add" id="Add" />
    <input type="submit" value="-" name="action:Sub" id="Sub" />
    <input type="submit" value="*" name="action:Mul" id="Mul" />
    <input type="submit" value="/" name="action:Div" id="Div" />
}
```

код контролера

```
// GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MultiButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Add")]
    public ActionResult Add(Calculator calc)
    {
        calc.Res = calc.A + calc.B;
        return View("Index", calc);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MultiButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Sub")]
    public ActionResult Sub(Calculator calc)
    {
        calc.Res = calc.A - calc.B;
        return View("Index", calc);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MultiButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Mul")]
    public ActionResult Mul(Calculator calc)
    {
        calc.Res = calc.A * calc.B;
        return View("Index", calc);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MultiButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Div")]
    public ActionResult Div(Calculator calc)
    {
        calc.Res = calc.A / calc.B;
        return View("Index", calc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте вот тут @: =  убрать знак =

Comment: @AndreiS.убрал. все тоже самое

Answer (score -1):

Да проблема может быть в том что нет SET или @ вот с этими штуками.

Да и вообще лучше используй public int Value {get; set;}

Это же всё таки контракт. А если и насетапят каким то образом и отправят, то ты же можешь проверить на back end side. Тут нестоит заморчиватся и клепать private и определять get; set;

Comment: в классе есть и get и set.